# Stubbing S3 presigned_url in AWS SDK v2

Tags: ruby, aws-sdk

I'm attempting to use the AWS Ruby SDK [response stubs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/ClientStubs.html#stub_responses-instance_method) to test some error handling in my interactions with S3.

I've been able to stub a simplistic `put_object` case, but for some reason I cannot stub [`presigned_url`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#presigned_url-instance_method). It's important to note that I am using an older version of the SDK.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'aws-sdk', '2.3.22'
```

```
describe 'Stubbing AWS' do
  module S3Helper
    def self.presigned_url(object_key:, client:)
      resource = ::Aws::S3::Resource.new(:client => client)
      bucket = resource.bucket('my-great-bucket')
      bucket
        .object(object_key)
        .presigned_url(:get)
    end
  end

  it 'should allow me to stub signed_url' do
    test_client = Aws::S3::Client.new(
      :access_key_id => ENV['SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
      :region => ENV['AWS_REGION']
    )

    test_client.stub_responses(:get_object 'NotFound')

    expect do
      S3Helper.presigned_url(
        object_key: 'my-key',
        client: client
      )
    end.to raise(/NotFound/)
  end
end
```

The test fails because the response does not trigger the `NotFound` error, even though I can clearly see that a `get_object` request was made (and a fake response was returned) in the application logs.

I'm currently solving around this by passing a mock client to my service, and stubbing out the `object` and `presigned_url` methods, but I'd prefer to have the SDK do the mocking for me. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not stubbing the response correctly.

Try this way:

```
test_client.stub_responses(:get_object, 'NotFound')
```

From the documentation, I see that the `stub_responses` method accepts an array of arguments, not a hash.

Comment: I think you are right about the syntax (i'll update my question) but that still does not affect the result from the client

Answer (score 0):

Though I am replying to this after ages, for whatever its worth
generate_presigned_url is not actually an AWS API request like S3::ListBucket or something. It never hits any AWS service at all.

I'm fairly sure it just uses your local credentials to create a signature for the request as if it were going to make it, then puts it in the query parameters of a url that is effectively the request in url form -- signature and all